# Use different logic based on current DataAreaId

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

**Question**

What is the best practice way to execute different logic based on a user's current DataAreaId in Dynamics AX 2012 R2?

**Background and Context**

We have an SSRS report which has been customised so that for one legal entity (dataareaid) we see a different design than for other legal entities.
The `main` method of the `CustCollectionJourController` class has been modified as below:

```
public static void main(Args _args)
{
    CustCollectionJourController controller = CustCollectionJourController::construct();

    controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr (CustomCustCollJourReport, OurNewDesignName));
    controller.parmArgs(_args);
    controller.startOperation();
}
```

I'm not an AX or SSRS developer, but spotted this code whilst trying to help resolve an issue related to this report's behaviour in our test environment (I develop in several other languages, including C#, so am fairly comfortable reading the code).

I believe this code has an issue; i.e. all legal entities will receive the `OurNewDesignName` because there's no logic to determine when to use `OurOriginalDesignName`.

I've communicated this concern to our developers, but am wary of saying "base the design on the data area id" in case it's misinterpreted (we've had issues historically) in a way which results in a non-dynamic solution such as:

```cs
switch (currentDataAreaid)
{
    case 'DAT': //the dataareaid of the legal entity wanting the new report
        controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(CCICustCollJourReport, OurNewDesignName)); 
        break;
    default: 
        controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(CCICustCollJourReport, OurOriginalDesignName)); 
        break;
}
```

But rather have the functionality associated with the data area id in a way such as:

```cs
switch (GetCompanyPreference(currentDataAreaid, 'CustomCustCollJourReportDesignPreference'))
{
    case 'OurNewDesignName':
        controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(CCICustCollJourReport, OurNewDesignName)); 
        break;
    default: 
        controller.parmReportName(ssrsReportStr(CCICustCollJourReport, OurOriginalDesignName)); 
        break;
}
```

I suspect there's a best practice version of this (i.e. some existing function replacing what I've used `GetCompanyPreference` for above), but I can't find any code samples or documentation on this / don't know the correct terminology to search for.

Comment: Take a look at [Print management](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309604.aspx), you can [set the report format/design for each company](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/hh209383.aspx) there. Please be aware that does not necessarily make the code you spotted incorrect. AX will use the design given in the code if the report is not printed using print management.

Comment: Notice the `PrintMgmtReportFormat.populate()` method, which populates the table (in current company). Total crap!

Comment: Thanks @FH-Inway; that resolves my concern about this being hard coded.

Comment: For my curiosity, if instead of being a report this was simply business logic, what would be the correct way to code this; i.e. would we just create flags in the relevant module's parameters table and define flag values per company; or is there a preferred way?

Comment: Depends on the requirements, but yes, usually parameters are used to provide company specific functionality.

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen oooh, pretty. ;)